# $|x+y|=|x-2y|$ where x and y are vectors

Tags: vectors

If x and y are non zero vectors such that $|x+y|=|x-2y|$ then we have to prove 2x.y=|y|$^2$ .

I thought about it alot , but don't any start .

can anybody provide me a hint .

Comment: You can start by squaring both sides and use the fact that x.x = |x|^2. Assuming '.' is referring to dot product here.

Comment: @thedilated Thanks I got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\cdot y$ denotes the dot product (or inner product), then
$$
|ax+by|^2=(ax+by)\cdot(ax+by)=a^2x\cdot x+abx\cdot y+aby\cdot x+b^2y\cdot y
$$
Can you go on?